# Reference other collections with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

In Mongoose, I am able to extract data that references another Collection.

For instance, I can do

```
Comment.find().populate('user').then(comment => {
  //
})
```

such that `comment` has all its normal fields (`text`, `createdAt`, etc.), but it is also populated with all the fields from `user`, such that it now has `comment.user.username`, `comment.user.full_name`, etc.

How can I obtain the same with `PyMongo`?

Comment: Why? `.populate()` is kind of an old concept that is basically superseded by [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in modern MongoDB releases. All `.populate()` actually does is issue another query and merges the results with the previous query. `$lookup` is a lot more effective as it happens on the "server" as opposed to pulling all results over the network to the "client".

Comment: Oh didn't knew. How can I use `$lookup` with pymongo?

Comment: Same way you use it with any language. All query and aggregation DSL does not change, no matter which language is used.